# React: Passing a variable from one component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React. All I want to do is pass some constants from parent component to a child component.

```html
import './App.css';
import { Display } from './Display';
import { Card } from './Card';

export function App() {
    const PIinput = {
        label: 'Personal Information',
        inputs: ['Name', 'Adress', 'Email', 'Phone'],
    };
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <Card props={PIinput}></Card>
            </div>
            <Display />
        </>
    );
}
```

```html
export function Card(props) {
    console.log(props, props.label);
    return (
        <div className='card'>
            <h2>{props.label}</h2>
            <form>
                {props.inputs.map((item) => {
                    return <h3>{item}</h3>;
                })}
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

So when I pass PIinput to the Card component and try to console.log props it displays my object, but when I try to console.log or use props.label or props.inputs I get an undefined.

How do I properly pass these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property you are passing to `<Card props={PInput} >` is named `props` because that is what you named the attribute in the tag.

So in:

```js
export function Card(props) {
    console.log(props, props.label);
```

you now have the properties of Card in an object named `props`, and one of the properties you have passed to it is named `props`.

To log the `label` value, you would use:

```js
console.log(props.props.label);
```

Ultimately naming a property in a JSX tag `props` is a bad and confusing idea.  Consider naming the prop something else, such as:

```js
<Card xxx={PInput} />
```

then the code to see the label would be:

```js
export function Card(props) {
    console.log(props.xxx.label);
```

The input to a component is a SINGLE argument whose value is an OBJECT.  You can name that argument anything you like, but traditionally we all tend to name it `props`.

The `props` argument (or whatever you call it) will have an element for each of the attributes passed to the component via its JSX tag, and that object will have some other elements in it that React puts there, such as `.children`

`.children` is the JSX of the tags put between the start and end tags for your component:

```js
<Card>
  <div><p>hello</p></div>
</Card>
```

would have `props.children` equal to `<div><p>hello</p></div>`

Answer (score 0):

`<Card PIinput={PIinput} />` on parent.

And in child component Card destructure props like this.

```
function Card({PIinput}) {
  console.log(PIinput);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You had mistaken to rules of passing props. Let it clear first.

You can get codeSandbox link [Here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/props-fxpjlw?file=%2Fsrc%2FCard.js%3A1%2C1-14%2C1).

App.js

```
    import Card from "./Card";
export default function App() {
  const PIinput = {
    label: "Personal Information",
    inputs: ["Name", "Adress", "Email", "Phone"],
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Card PIinput={PIinput}></Card>
      </div>
      {/* <Display /> */}
    </>
  );
}
```

Card.js

```
export default function Card({ PIinput }) {
  console.log(PIinput, PIinput.label);
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <h2>{PIinput.label}</h2>
      <form>
        {PIinput.inputs.map((item) => {
          return <h3>{item}</h3>;
        })}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```